# How to disable focus assist light in MediaCapture?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I am trying to disable the focus assist light and I cannot find a valid method or property in `MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl`

Windows Phone's camera app allows configuring the focus assist light:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [CameraManualControls SDK sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraManualControls) on the Microsoft Windows Universal Samples GitHub repo.

You'll find the necessary property for setting it under the `FlashControl`:

```
private void FocusLightCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var flashControl = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl;

    flashControl.AssistantLightEnabled = (FocusLightCheckBox.IsChecked == true);
}
```